# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.id' inconnu dans where clause ( Symfony 5 , API Platform )

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I have 2 classes , Class Child "Livreur" inherite  from Class Parent "Users" .
Problem in return data after insert by API Plateform . (it inserted by success but data deosn't returned + doesn't insert in table Users, before that it inserted in Users+Livreur but now no ).

Class "Users" (parent) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping ;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsersRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"post"={},"get"={}},
 *     itemOperations={"get","put"={"denormalization_Context"={"groups"={"put"}}}}
 * )
 */

class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Expression("this.getPassword() == this.getRepassword()",message="Mot de pass doit etre le meme dans les 2 deux champs")
     */
    private $repassword;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $cin;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $dtn;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $dtype;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $img;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $rib;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @Groups({"put"})
     */
    private $tel;

    protected function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function setRoles(string $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cin;
    }

    public function setCin(string $cin): self
    {
        $this->cin = $cin;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDtn(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dtn;
    }

    public function setDtn(\DateTimeInterface $dtn): self
    {
        $this->dtn = $dtn;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDtype(): ?string
    {
        return $this->dtype;
    }

    public function setDtype(?string $dtype): self
    {
        $this->dtype = $dtype;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImg(): ?string
    {
        return $this->img;
    }

    public function setImg(?string $img): self
    {
        $this->img = $img;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRib(): ?string
    {
        return $this->rib;
    }

    public function setRib(?string $rib): self
    {
        $this->rib = $rib;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(?string $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    public function setTel(string $tel): self
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    public function getRepassword()
    {
        return $this->repassword;
    }

    public function setRepassword($repassword): void
    {
        $this->repassword = $repassword;
    }
}
```

Class Livreur (child) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\LivreurRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LivreurRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class Livreur extends Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $type_vehicule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $permis;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $disponibilite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $coffre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $log;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Commande::class, mappedBy="livreur")
     */
    private $commandes;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Conge::class, mappedBy="livreur")
     */
    private $conges;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Agence::class, inversedBy="livreurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $agence;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=SalaireEmp::class, inversedBy="livreur", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $salaire_emp;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Ville::class, inversedBy="livreurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ville;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commandes = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->conges = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTypeVehicule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type_vehicule;
    }

    public function setTypeVehicule(string $type_vehicule): self
    {
        $this->type_vehicule = $type_vehicule;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPermis(): ?string
    {
        return $this->permis;
    }

    public function setPermis(string $permis): self
    {
        $this->permis = $permis;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDisponibilite(): ?int
    {
        return $this->disponibilite;
    }

    public function setDisponibilite(int $disponibilite): self
    {
        $this->disponibilite = $disponibilite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCoffre(): ?float
    {
        return $this->coffre;
    }

    public function setCoffre(float $coffre): self
    {
        $this->coffre = $coffre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLog(): ?string
    {
        return $this->log;
    }

    public function setLog(?string $log): self
    {
        $this->log = $log;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Commande[]
     */
    public function getCommandes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->commandes;
    }

    public function addCommande(Commande $commande): self
    {
        if (!$this->commandes->contains($commande)) {
            $this->commandes[] = $commande;
            $commande->setLivreur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCommande(Commande $commande): self
    {
        if ($this->commandes->removeElement($commande)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($commande->getLivreur() === $this) {
                $commande->setLivreur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Conge[]
     */
    public function getConges(): Collection
    {
        return $this->conges;
    }

    public function addConge(Conge $conge): self
    {
        if (!$this->conges->contains($conge)) {
            $this->conges[] = $conge;
            $conge->setLivreur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeConge(Conge $conge): self
    {
        if ($this->conges->removeElement($conge)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($conge->getLivreur() === $this) {
                $conge->setLivreur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAgence(): ?Agence
    {
        return $this->agence;
    }

    public function setAgence(?Agence $agence): self
    {
        $this->agence = $agence;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalaireEmp(): ?SalaireEmp
    {
        return $this->salaire_emp;
    }

    public function setSalaireEmp(?SalaireEmp $salaire_emp): self
    {
        $this->salaire_emp = $salaire_emp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?Ville
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(?Ville $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to set an inheritance mapping strategy. Here is an example:

```
// (..)

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsersRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"users" = "Users", "livreur" = "Livreur"})
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *     collectionOperations={"post"={},"get"={}},
 *     itemOperations={"get","put"={"denormalization_Context"={"groups"={"put"}}}}
 * )
 */

class Users implements UserInterface
{
// (..)
```

This will add an extra field "discr" to the tables of both your classes so you will have to update their table configurations, for example with:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

or if you use migrations:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

For explanation of Mapping Strategies and their alternatives see the [Inheritance Mapping page on doctrine-project.org](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)